# Python and Web applications

Tags: python, urllib

I want to start writing python to support some of my web applications.
Mainly i'm trying to fetch pages, send POST data to urls and some string manipulation.

I understand that there are some disadvantages with the urllib in the new versions.

Can anyone please tell me which release is best for my needs?

Thanks

Comment: Define "best" please?   Does "best" mean "most use of Oracle software"?  Does "best" mean "can't run in VMWare and must run on native hardware"?  What does "best" mean to you?

Comment: best for MY needs as they are defined above.

Comment: I think I wasn't too clear. My question is regarding the version of Python which is  best for my needs.

Comment: "best" is not defined above.  You've listed something you want to do. ("start writing python").  "Best" must have some aspect or feature you want to optimize.  If you can't define "best" then take the word out of your question.

Comment: "the version of Python which is best for my needs".  (1) **update** your question to be correct and complete.  (2) define "best".  I believe that "best" means "Uses Microsoft Licenses."  Do you agree?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1.  Use `urllib2` to fetch pages.  Save them in flat files

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Step 2.  Use  a WSGI-based server like `werkzeug` to serve those pages.

http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/

When you get that working, plug it into a proper web server (like Apache) with `mod_wsgi`.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

Comment: Should I apply all the above when using the latest Python version? or one of the older ones?

Comment: @John Daman: **Update** your question to include asking which version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your needs ... but did you try twill. It can fetch pages, fill forms, and whatever you need. It contains a "scripting languages" and can be embedded in your python application.

http://twill.idyll.org/